# Cartouches in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to make an Egyptian cartouche in CSS, of the usual form :

[image]

The border isn't terribly hard to do, with just

```
.cartouche
{
    border: 4px double black;
    border-radius:20px;
    display:inline;
    padding:3px 5px;
}
```

which gives for instance

[image]

It is lacking the bar of the cartouche, though. What would be a good way to add such a bar to the edge of a border?

Comment: I'd suggest using an `:after` pseudo element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the vertical bar at the right side, you could use a pseudo element and the following settings:

```css
.cartouche {
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px double black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.cartouche:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  width: 0;
  top: -4px;
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  border-right: 4px double black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cartouche"></div>
```

or, a variation where that bar covers the rounded border and has a closed border line itself:

```css
.cartouche {
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px double black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.cartouche:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  width: 2px;
  top: -4px;
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="cartouche"></div>
```